# java setter list object main not working

Tags: java, program-entry-point, setter

Hello I was wondering how to create an object in the list that is from another object.
For example I have a class `Analysator` and a class `RoleGame`.
There is no problem with the getters and setters.

But `analysator1.setListRollenspellen(new RoleGame());` doesn't work.

### Analysator class

```
public ArrayList<RoleGame> listRoleGame = new ArrayList<RoleGame>();    

//getter
public ArrayList<RoleGame> getListRoleGame() {
    return listRoleGame;
}

// setter
public void setListRoleGame(ArrayList<RoleGame> listRoleGame) {
    this.listRoleGame = listRoleGame;
}
```

### Main class

```
Analysator analysator1 = new Analysator();
analysator1.setListRoleGame(new RoleGame()); // <-- here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analysator class expect the list as input, so provide a list to it:

```
Analysator analysator1 = new Analysator();
analysator1.setListRoleGame(Arrays.asList(new RoleGame())); // Should work
```

Answer (score 2):

Your setter method expects ArrayList and you are passing RoleGame. If you want it to work, you could do something like:

```
public void setListRoleGame(RoleGame roleGame) {
     this.listRoleGame.add(roleGame);
}
```

Comment: strange advice. call this setter x100 times and you'll get 100 elements in the list. either rename it to addRoleGame or change the code this.list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(roleGame))